# It seems 15.10 has too many problems, is this natural or Canonical should resolve the bugs?

Tags: discussion

It seems that *Ubuntu 15.10* is bringing up a lot of questions here on Ask Ubuntu. Is this natural? (Newbies getting excited to actually test it out, they know nothing so a lot of problems/questions bring up, but then all of that passes.) Or it is actually buggy?

Comment: I only see ~300 or so 15.10 questions so far? What leads you to believe that that's an indication of quality?

Comment: Can you provide any examples of the `bugs` ? Installation issues and driver issues are really common here on any release of Ubuntu, new or not, as you said yourself, "exited noobs" wanting the latest something they don't yet understand, these questions are not necessarily bugs in Ubuntu but user error. Also any bugs related to any 3rd party software is not Canonical's fault. This site is not a good gauge of how buggy the current release is.

Comment: Maybe it's only sometimes, now it's all 15.04

Comment: Nah, 15.04 was much more problematic because they switched from upstart to systemd. I even read somewhere that 15.10 was a really quiet release.

Comment: 15.10 is the best yet :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's common that after new release comes out a lot of questions are asked about it.

15.10 came out 10 days ago. We're going to see more 15.10-targeted questions than anything else for a little while.

Comment: Alright, case number 1 (Probably not "Canonical doesn't know 2 + 2", figure it out people.)

Comment: The answer is 4!!

Comment: 2 + 2 = 5 for extremely large values of 2